# html unicode fire fox & chrome not the same?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, unicode

I know that is probably a very silly question, but I've looked and have not found anything on my issue that seems up to date.

Chrome: [image] (Would like firefox to display the same as this.)

What firefox shows:

[image]

I have no knowledge on why this is happening, please feed me know-how.

Code:

```css
#menuBtnOff {
  font-size: 27px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
  <li> <span id="menuBtnOff" onclick="menuIn()">&#x2573;</span></li>
```

Comment: Looks like they are using different fonts.Try using `font-family` to use the same font on both browsers.

Comment: @Sirko I had a try a that before posting, did not seem to do anything. Would still be different on chrome and firefox with and without a font for me.

Comment: Maybe the font you chose didn't have that character. You'd have to find a font that supports that character and then it would probably look the same on both browsers

Comment: Anyone know of a way to test for unicode support for fonts?

Comment: From my browsers: FF is using "Segoe UI Symbol" and Chrome "Lucida Sans Unicode". Both symbols, however, look pretty much the same to me.